# Can't show image with OpenCV in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, opencv

The project's result will show a window contain picture. But it just show a console window with message

> "press  to close this window qt"

and don't show anything more. I run with MSCV2010 Release.

What can I do now?

Here is my .pro:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = OpenCV
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
#CONFIG   -= qt

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include

CONFIG(debug,debug|release){
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_core231.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_highgui231.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_imgproc231.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_features2d231.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_calib3d231.lib
}

CONFIG(release,debug|release){
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_core231.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_highgui231.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_imgproc231.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_features2d231.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_calib3d231.lib
}
```

and my main():

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Mat image=imread("C:/Desert.jpg");
    imshow("image",image);

    return a.exec();
}
```

=======================================

Finally, I found my problem.

First, I run executable file of my project at "OpenCV-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-*MSVC2010*_Qt_SDK__Release\release". And I found that, some dll file is missing. I copied them to System32 Folder and it run successfully! Yeah!

Actually, I put paths of these dll into system environment. But it still show that it can't find dll files. What's happen?

Comment: Quick hint: replace `"C:/Desert.jpg"` with `"C:\\Desert.jpg"`.

Comment: yes, I did it. But not thing change

Comment: @vahancho Does OpenCV really require platform-specific path separators, and does not convert `/` to ``\`` on Windows?

Comment: @hyde, to be honest, I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks guys for answering my question! Finally, I found my problem. You can see it at the end of my question.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

if you use imshow(), you need waitKey() as well, else nothing will be shown. ( it does not only wait for keys or such, the whole window-message pump is hidden in there, so, no blitting without that )

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Mat image=imread("C:/Desert.jpg");
    imshow("image",image);
    waitKey(0); // wait forever until a key was pressed

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I did it too. But nothing change.